# Iterating two dataframes and providing minimum rank on multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to iterate through two dataframes, one being large (with multiple columns and non null cols value)  and one being small (with some common cols and null value in it).

The large dataframe is actual customer data with all attributes and other one is ranking data. I am trying to stamp minimum rank to all customer comparing it with ranking data.

The Lager dataframe look like this -

```
CUST_ID,DTL1,DTL2,DTLS3,AGE_BAND,SCORE,STATE,ATTR_1,ATTR_2,ATTR_3
1,xx,xx,xx,A1,S1,MH,1,1,6
2,xx,xx,xx,A1,S2,MH,1,2,7
3,xx,xx,xx,A2,S3,GJ,2,2,7
4,xx,xx,xx,A3,S1,RJ,1,2,6
5,xx,xx,xx,A2,S1,GJ,2,1,6
6,xx,xx,xx,A3,S3,RJ,1,2,7
```

and the ranking data -

```
Rank,AGE_BAND,SCORE,STATE,ATTR_1,ATTR_2
1,A1,S1,MH,Null,Null
2,A1,Null,MH,Null,1
3,Null,S1,GJ,Null,1
4,Null,S1,GJ,2,Null
```

**Here, If we see, then cust_1 satisfy for both the rank- 1 and 2, but we would go for minimum i.e. 1. Same goes for Cust_5, rank 3.**

I tried creating a nested for loop; the outer loop iterating through the large dataframe and the inner loop iterating through the small dataframe however I am having difficulties.

I'm looking for a way to identify that the "col_name" and "value" in my small dataframe that matches my large dataframe when not null and then assigning minimum rank to it.

I am trying to write some thing like below:

```
for cust in Data_Cust.iterrows():       
    for rank in Data_rank.iterrows():       #if we can eliminate columns where its value are null for individual rank
        if rank.col_name == cust.col_name && rank.col_value == cust.value  ##something from which we can match col/val name with col/value name of both dfs
        
            #create a list and appended all eligible ranks
            #selecting minimun rank at the end
            #appending list and min rank in Data_cust
```

Comment: show your work/code and what you did also what is your expected output

Comment: I haven't able to write the complete executable code at moment but trying to built something like mentioned in question. @Jimmar

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Do you need a way to compare every member from df1 to every member of df2 and then calculate the best result?

Comment: @MLAlex Thats correct! Every member from df1 should be compared to df2 when not null and then selecting min rank.

Comment: You can try using a nested apply function. For example use .apply on first column to get every member at once and after that you use an apply function for the other column. So you can compare the first member of column1 to every member of column2 and then have the next member of column1.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this to create a series that maps the values in the columns to the minimum  rank for that value.  Next, use that series to map the values on a row for a customer.

```
cols=['AGE_BAND', 'SCORE', 'STATE']
m = pd.concat([df_rank[[i, 'Rank']].replace('Null', np.nan).drop_duplicates([i], keep='first').dropna()\
       .set_index(i)['Rank'] for i in cols])
m
```

Then,

```
df.set_index('CUST_ID')[['AGE_BAND', 'SCORE', 'STATE']].stack().map(m).unstack()
```

Output:

```
         AGE_BAND  SCORE  STATE
CUST_ID                        
1             1.0    1.0    1.0
2             1.0    NaN    1.0
3             NaN    NaN    3.0
4             NaN    1.0    NaN
5             NaN    1.0    3.0
6             NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Minimum rank per customer:

```
CUST_ID
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    1.0
5    3.0
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix comparison to do a quick match, and a weighting system to prioritise the order of columns (optional).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
id_df = pd.read_csv('id.txt', index_col=0)
rank_df = pd.read_csv('rank.txt', index_col=0)

cols_of_interest = id_df.iloc[:, [3,4,5,6,7]] # because you're not using all the columns
scaling = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])

final_ranks = []

for i in cols_of_interest.index:
    current_row = cols_of_interest.loc[i,:] # get the row of interest
    diff = (rank_df == current_row) # compare current row to ALL the rows in RANK_DF
    diff = diff * scaling # scale the columns by multiplying by the scale array (same length as number of columns)
    scores = diff.sum(axis=1) # sum up the scores by row
    final_ranks.append(scores.idxmax()) # get the index (ie rank) of the first occurrence of the max score, which if RANK_DF is sorted, should give you the small rank that meets the criteria.

print(final_ranks)
```

Results in:

```
[1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```